# Intuition on convergence of Fibonacci-like sequences

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

I can prove this many different ways - but still, a clear insight eludes me. It's one of those things that, if I were to forget the proof, I would also forget why it's true - since I can't see the truth outright.

Given some Fibonacci-like sequence $\{F_n\}$, it is clear that if $\{\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\}$ converges, it must converge to $\phi$, the golden ratio.

However, why $\{\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\}$ converges is harder to see (again, I *can* prove it). Why does recursively adding the 2 previous terms together result in a sequence of numbers who look more and more "similar".

I've tried reasoning through a few different proofs, based on convergence to $\phi$, being Cauchy, and continued fractions - but still don't see it plainly.

If someone has insight, and can explain in simple English, maybe that will help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is one of your ratios $F_{n+1}/F_n$ then the next is $(1+x)/x$.
The map $g(x)=(1+x)/x$ has fixed points $\frac12(1\pm\sqrt5)$
and $\tau=\frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$ is an attracting fixed point: $|g'(\tau)|<1$.
This means that if $x$ gets close to $\tau$, $g(x)$ will be even closer,
$g(g(x))$ closer still, etc.

Comment: (+1) Banach fixed-point theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) strikes again.

Comment: This was already the direction my head was headed in. The ref to the Banach fixed point theorem was a real help, and organized some of my thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: @zac I solved your problem without words " the Banach fixed point theorem", but I showed what this theorem says exactly! See my post please.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}}$, where $a_1=1$.

Thus, $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}$.

Since $a_n\geq1$, we obtain:
$$\left|a_{n+1}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}\right|=$$
$$=\left|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{2}{\sqrt5+1}\right|=\frac{\left|\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}-a_n\right|}{a_n\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}\leq\frac{|\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}-a_n|}{\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}$$
and since $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}>1$, we are done!

Comment: Hey Michael - thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this was something I was already aware of, but for whatever reason, didn't help me "see" the solution. For whatever reason, viewing things as $a_n = g(g(g(...(a_0)...)))$ with $\phi$ as an attraction point "clicked". Not taking away from the validity of your answer - just that different arguments seem to appeal to different minds :)

Comment: Dear @zac  My solution is $|a_n-\phi|\leq\frac{1}{\phi}|a_{n-1}-\phi|\leq\frac{1}{\phi^2}|a_{n-2}-\phi|\leq...\leq\frac{1}{\phi^{n-1}}|a_1-\phi|$, which can be less that all $\epsilon>0$ for some $n$. It's just proof without words about Banach.